# Firing events on CSS class changes in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-events

How can I fire an event if a CSS class is added or changed using jQuery?
Does changing of a CSS class fire the jQuery `change()` event?

Comment: 7 years later, with the fairly wide adoption of MutationObservers in modern browsers, the accepted answer here should really updated to be [Mr Br's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24284069/663246).

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157963/is-it-possible-to-listen-to-a-style-change-event

Comment: In completion to Jason's answer, i found this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19401707/1579667

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Whenever you change a class in your script, you could use a `trigger` to raise your own event.

```
$(this).addClass('someClass');
$(mySelector).trigger('cssClassChanged')
....
$(otherSelector).bind('cssClassChanged', data, function(){ do stuff });
```

but otherwise, no, there's no baked-in way to fire an event when a class changes. `change()` only fires after focus leaves an input whose input has been altered.

```js
$(function() {
  var button = $('.clickme')
      , box = $('.box')
  ;
  
  button.on('click', function() { 
    box.removeClass('box');
    $(document).trigger('buttonClick');
  });
            
  $(document).on('buttonClick', function() {
    box.text('Clicked!');
  });
});
```

```css
.box { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">Hi</div>
<button class="clickme">Click me</button>
```

[More info on jQuery Triggers](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger#eventdata)

Comment: What's the deal with triggering the event which then calls a function? Why not call the function directly, instead of triggering it?

Comment: Triggering is a mechanism that will allow certain elements to "subscribe" to an event. that way, when the event is triggered, those events can all happen at once and run their respective functionality. for instance, if i have one object that changes from red to blue and three objects waiting for it to change, when it changes, i can just trigger the `changeColor` event, and all those objects subscribing to that event can react accordingly.

Comment: Seems a bit strange that the OP wants to listen to a 'cssClassChanged' event; surely the class was added as a result of some other 'application' event such as 'colourChanged' which would make more sense to announce with trigger as I can't quite imagine why anything would be interested in specifically a className change, it's more the result of the classNameChange surely?

Comment: If it was specifically a className change that was of interest then I'd imagine decorating jQuery.fn.addClass to trigger 'cssClassChanged' would be more sensible like @micred said

Comment: @riscarrott i don't presume to know the OP's application. I'm just presenting them with the concept of pub/sub and they can apply it however they'd like. Disputing what the actual event name should be with the amount of info given is silly.

Comment: It's not correct that there is no baked-in way to fire and event. I have added answer bellow which explains Mutation Observers a bit, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed/24284069#24284069 . With mutation observers you can get real events on attribute change, without need to trigger anything manually.

Comment: ...with tons of extra code, less cross-browser support, less flexibility, and events firing every time something changes on the page leading to a decrease in performance. MutationObservers are cool for sure, though.

Comment: It's future, most of latest browser support it, and it's appended to every element only in example, in answer I said it's not suggested to do it, you should append it only to elements on which you need listener...how browsers support it check out at http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver
This way your are making it more generic, instead of triggering event every time manually, for me that is right approach.
I am just interested if you would accept it if (when) jQuery adds it as default feature...

Answer (score 143):

IMHO the better solution is to combine two answers by @RamboNo5 and @Jason

I mean overridding addClass function and adding a custom event called `cssClassChanged`

```
// Create a closure
(function(){
    // Your base, I'm in it!
    var originalAddClassMethod = jQuery.fn.addClass;

    jQuery.fn.addClass = function(){
        // Execute the original method.
        var result = originalAddClassMethod.apply( this, arguments );

        // trigger a custom event
        jQuery(this).trigger('cssClassChanged');

        // return the original result
        return result;
    }
})();

// document ready function
$(function(){
    $("#YourExampleElementID").bind('cssClassChanged', function(){ 
        //do stuff here
    });
});
```

Comment: This indeed sounds like the best approach, but although I bind the event only to "#YourExampleElementID", it appears that all class changes (i.e., on any of the elements on my page) are handled by this handler... any thoughts?

Comment: It works fine for me @FilipeCorreia . Can you please provide a jsfiddle with replicating your case?

Comment: @Goldentoa11 You should take time some evening or weekend and monitor everything that happens on a typical pageload which uses advertising heavily. You will be blown away by the volume of scripts attempting (sometimes unsuccessfully in the most spectacular way) to do things like this. I've run across pages which fire tens of DOMNodeInserted/DOMSubtreeModified events per second, totaling hundreds of events by the time you get to `$()`, when the real action starts.

Comment: You would presumably also want to support triggering the same event on removeClass

Comment: Arash, I guess I understand why @FilipeCorreia was experiencing some issues with this approach: if you bind this `cssClassChanged` event to an element, you must be aware that it will be fired even when its child change their class. Therefore if for example you don't want to fire this event for them, just add something like `$("#YourExampleElementID *").on('cssClassChanged', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });` after your bind. Anyway, really nice solution, thanks!

Comment: Beware of a Stack Overflow if you were to alter the css class in the listener; The Solution works perfect for me!

Answer (score 64):

If you want to detect class change, best way is to use Mutation Observers, which gives you complete control over any attribute change. However you need to define listener yourself, and append it to element you are listening. Good thing is that you don't need to trigger anything manually once listener is appended.

```
$(function() {
(function($) {
    var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

    $.fn.attrchange = function(callback) {
        if (MutationObserver) {
            var options = {
                subtree: false,
                attributes: true
            };

            var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                mutations.forEach(function(e) {
                    callback.call(e.target, e.attributeName);
                });
            });

            return this.each(function() {
                observer.observe(this, options);
            });

        }
    }
})(jQuery);

//Now you need to append event listener
$('body *').attrchange(function(attrName) {

    if(attrName=='class'){
            alert('class changed');
    }else if(attrName=='id'){
            alert('id changed');
    }else{
        //OTHER ATTR CHANGED
    }

});
});
```

In this example event listener is appended to every element, but you don't want that in most cases (save memory). Append this "attrchange" listener to element you want observe.

Comment: this seems like it is doing the exact same thing that the accepted answer is doing, but with more code, unsupported on some browsers, and with less flexibility. the only benefit this appears to have is that it will fire _every time_ something changes on the page, which will absolutely destroy your performance...

Comment: Your statement in answer is incorrect @Json, this is actually the way to do it if you don't want to active any trigger manually, but have it active automatically. It's not only benefit it's the benefit, cos this was asked in question. Second, this was just an example, and as it says in example it's not suggested to append event listener to every element but only to elements you want to listen, so I don't understand why will it destroy performance. And last thing, it's future, most of latest browser support it, http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver .Please reconsider edit, it's right way.

Comment: The [insertionQ library](https://github.com/naugtur/insertionQuery) lets you catch DOM nodes showing up if they match a selector. It has wider browser support because it doesn't use `DOMMutationObserver`.

Comment: This is a great solution. In particular for starting and stopping canvas or SVG animations when a class is added or removed. In my case for making sure they are not running when scrolled out of view. Sweet!

Comment: For 2019, this should be the accepted answer. All major browsers seem to support Mutation Observers now, and this solution doesn't require to fire events manually or rewrite basic jQuery functionality.

Answer (score 53):

I would suggest you override the addClass function. You can do it this way:

```
// Create a closure
(function(){
    // Your base, I'm in it!
    var originalAddClassMethod = jQuery.fn.addClass;

    jQuery.fn.addClass = function(){
        // Execute the original method.
        var result = originalAddClassMethod.apply( this, arguments );

        // call your function
        // this gets called everytime you use the addClass method
        myfunction();

        // return the original result
        return result;
    }
})();

// document ready function
$(function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Combining this with Jason's $(mySelector).trigger('cssClassChanged') would be the best approach I think.

Comment: There's a plugin that does this generically: http://github.com/aheckmann/jquery.hook/blob/master/jquery.hook.js

Comment: Seems like a great way to confuse a future maintainer.

Comment: Don't forget to return the result of the original method.

Comment: For reference, you are using the Proxy Pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern

Answer (score 22):

Just a proof of concept:

Look at the gist to see some annotations and stay up-to-date:

**https://gist.github.com/yckart/c893d7db0f49b1ea4dfb**

```
(function ($) {
  var methods = ['addClass', 'toggleClass', 'removeClass'];

  $.each(methods, function (index, method) {
    var originalMethod = $.fn[method];

    $.fn[method] = function () {
      var oldClass = this[0].className;
      var result = originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
      var newClass = this[0].className;

      this.trigger(method, [oldClass, newClass]);

      return result;
    };
  });
}(window.jQuery || window.Zepto));
```

The usage is quite simple, just add a new listender on the node you want to observe and manipulate the classes as usually:

```
var $node = $('div')

// listen to class-manipulation
.on('addClass toggleClass removeClass', function (e, oldClass, newClass) {
  console.log('Changed from %s to %s due %s', oldClass, newClass, e.type);
})

// make some changes
.addClass('foo')
.removeClass('foo')
.toggleClass('foo');
```

Comment: This worked for me, except I could not read old or new class with the removeClass method.

Comment: @slashdottir Can you create a fiddle and explain **what** exactly *doesn't work*.

Comment: Yeah... does not work.  
TypeError: this[0] is undefined in «return this[0].className;»

Comment: it works but sometimes (why ?), `this[0]` is undefined ... simply replace the end of the lines with `var oldClass` and `var newClass` with the following assignment: `= (this[0] ? this[0].className : "");`

Answer (score 9):

using latest jquery mutation

```
var $target = jQuery(".required-entry");
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                    if (mutation.attributeName === "class") {
                        var attributeValue = jQuery(mutation.target).prop(mutation.attributeName);
                        if (attributeValue.indexOf("search-class") >= 0){
                            // do what you want
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
            observer.observe($target[0],  {
                attributes: true
            });
```

// any code which update div having class **required-entry** which is in $target 
like $target.addClass('search-class');

Comment: Nice solution, I'm using it. However, I'm using react and one of the problem is that I add an observer each time the web element is virtually generated. Is there a way to check if an observer is already present?

Comment: I think this has been depreciated and should not be used according to [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe

Comment: @WebDude0482  MutationObserver.observe is not deprecated as it is an "Instance Method" of the "MutationObserver". See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 8):

`change()` does not fire when a CSS class is added or removed or the definition changes. It fires in circumstances like when a select box value is selected or unselected.

I'm not sure if you mean if the CSS class definition is changed (which can be done programmatically but is tedious and not generally recommended) or if a class is added or removed to an element. There is no way to reliably capture this happening in either case.

You could of course create your own event for this but this can only be described as *advisory*. It won't capture code that isn't yours doing it.

Alternatively you could override/replace the `addClass()` (etc) methods in jQuery but this won't capture when it's done via vanilla Javascript (although I guess you could replace those methods too).

Answer (score 8):

There is one more way **without** triggering an custom event

[A jQuery Plug-in to monitor Html Element CSS Changes by Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/Feb/22/A-jQuery-Plugin-to-monitor-Html-Element-CSS-Changes)

Quoting from above

> The watch plug-in works by hooking up to DOMAttrModified in FireFox,
>   to onPropertyChanged in Internet Explorer, or by using a timer with
>   setInterval to handle the detection of changes for other browsers.
>   Unfortunately WebKit doesn’t support DOMAttrModified consistently at
>   the moment so Safari and Chrome currently have to use the slower
>   setInterval mechanism.

Answer (score 6):

Good question. I'm using the Bootstrap Dropdown Menu, and needed to execute an event when a Bootstrap Dropdown was hidden.  When the dropdown is opened, the containing div with a class name of "button-group" adds a class of "open"; and the button itself has an "aria-expanded" attribute set to true.  When the dropdown is closed, that class of "open" is removed from the containing div, and aria-expanded is switched from true to false.

That led me to this question, of how to detect the class change.

With Bootstrap, there are "Dropdown Events" that can be detected.  Look for "Dropdown Events" at this link.
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_dropdown.asp

Here is a quick-and-dirty example of using this event on a Bootstrap Dropdown.

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(event) {
    console.log('closed');
});
```

Now I realize this is more specific than the general question that's being asked. But I imagine other developers trying to detect an open or closed event with a Bootstrap Dropdown will find this helpful. Like me, they may initially go down the path of simply trying to detect an element class change (which apparently isn't so simple).  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to trigger a specific event you can override the method addClass() to fire a custom event called 'classadded'.

Here how:

```
(function() {
    var ev = new $.Event('classadded'),
        orig = $.fn.addClass;
    $.fn.addClass = function() {
        $(this).trigger(ev, arguments);
        return orig.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})();

$('#myElement').on('classadded', function(ev, newClasses) {
    console.log(newClasses + ' added!');
    console.log(this);
    // Do stuff
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can bind the DOMSubtreeModified event. I add an example here:

**HTML**

```
<div id="mutable" style="width:50px;height:50px;">sjdfhksfh<div>
<div>
  <button id="changeClass">Change Class</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#changeClass').click(function() {
    $('#mutable').addClass("red");
  });

  $('#mutable').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(e) {
      alert('class changed');
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hnCxK/13/

Answer (score 0):

if you know a what event changed the class in the first place you may use a slight delay on the same event and the check the for the class.
example

```
//this is not the code you control
$('input').on('blur', function(){
    $(this).addClass('error');
    $(this).before("<div class='someClass'>Warning Error</div>");
});

//this is your code
$('input').on('blur', function(){
    var el= $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        if ($(el).hasClass('error')){ 
            $(el).removeClass('error');
            $(el).prev('.someClass').hide();
        }
    },1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GuDCp/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeout_check_change_class;

function check_change_class( selector )
{
    $(selector).each(function(index, el) {
        var data_old_class = $(el).attr('data-old-class');
        if (typeof data_old_class !== typeof undefined && data_old_class !== false) 
        {

            if( data_old_class != $(el).attr('class') )
            {
                $(el).trigger('change_class');
            }
        }

        $(el).attr('data-old-class', $(el).attr('class') );

    });

    clearTimeout( timeout_check_change_class );
    timeout_check_change_class = setTimeout(check_change_class, 10, selector);
}
check_change_class( '.breakpoint' );


$('.breakpoint').on('change_class', function(event) {
    console.log('haschange');
});
```