# listen for any div that goes from display: none to display:block

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there any way to listen for elements being shown or hidden?

I would like categorically to--whenever an element goes from hidden to shown--put focus on the first input element within the newly shown element

I thought of attaching a click event to everything and putting it at the top of the document, thinking that would trigger before anything and I could track whether the clicked element's `next("div")` (or something) would have a css display property of `none`, then setting a small timeout, then setting the focus, but I get `undefined` when I try to access that CSS property

```
$("html").on("click", "body", function(){
   alert($(this).next("div").css("display")); //undefined
});
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't. Your best bet would be to poll for changes.

Comment: you realize that .next() only targets the very next element, regardless of the selector correct? the selector is applied after an element has been found.

Comment: Also, `<body></body>` shouldn't have a div after it....

Comment: The only way to do this is by using an interval or a self calling timeout that checks all divs on the page.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157963/is-it-possible-to-listen-to-a-style-change-event) may help you.

Comment: If you know exactly what makes it show/hide, you could monkeypatch that method so that it triggers an event.

Comment: @NelsonGaldemanGraziano has found the duplicate question.

Comment: everybody please check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this (it’s kind of a hack). If you monkey-patch the css/show/hide/toggle prototypes in jQuery, you can test if the element changes it’s `:hidden` attribute after a "tick" (I used 4ms). If it does, it has changed it’s visibility. This might not work as expected for animations etc, but should work fine otherwise.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Bh6dA/

```
$.each(['show','hide','css','toggle'], function(i, fn) {
    var o = $.fn[fn];
    $.fn[fn] = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                isHidden = $this.is(':hidden');
            setTimeout(function() {
                if( isHidden !== $this.is(':hidden') ) {
                    $this.trigger('showhide', isHidden);
                }
            },4);
        });
        return o.apply(this, arguments);
    };   
})
```

Now, just listen for the `showhide` event:

```
$('div').on('showhide', function(e, visible) {
    if ( visible ) {
        $(this).find('input:first').focus();
    }
});
```

Tada!

*PS: I love monkeypatching*

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
var allEls = $('body *');

function isDisplayBlock(arr) {
    var isBlock = [];
    $.each(arr, function(i, e){
        if ($(e).css('display') === 'block') {
            isBlock.push(e);
        }
    })
    return isBlock;
}
```

But ive no idea how to check if they changed, instead of just checking if they are block.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `$('div:visible')` to check whether  a div has `display: block` or `display: none`. Those are the only two values that `:visible` looks at anyway.

Source: [How do I check if an element is hidden in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/testing-if-something-is-hidden-with-jquery)

-edit-
I realise I didn't read thoroughly, you're asking about an event that tells you when display changed. There is none, see Nelson's comment on your question.