# how to make datatables expand when width/height changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

Hey I was wondering if anyone could help me with a problem I was having with datatables.

I am trying to create an event listener that will bind to changes in css so that when the width or height changes for the datatable it will activate.  This question is the code that I am using 
[Is it possible to listen to a "style change" event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157963/is-it-possible-to-listen-to-a-style-change-event) but I cant seem to understand what it is doing or understand why it wont work.

Here is my fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/2f2L6/2/

```
(function() {
var ev = new $.Event('style'),
    orig = $.fn.css;
$.fn.css = function() {
    orig.apply(this, arguments);
    $(this).trigger(ev);
}
```

When I try to change the height of it by displaying more rows I thought that the method would call but it doesn't. Any ideas?

thank you
James

Comment: I'm guessing dataTables doesn't really use your custom `css()` method, otherwise it should probably work.

Comment: It doesnt work because dataTables not are using `$(element).css()` for changing styles. It would be too slow. I can count to places where it is happening. It uses `.css()` to _read_ style values though. It is very easy to detect page length changes, if that is what you want.

Comment: Is there an example of the detecting page length changes? would this help with the problem of the datatables changing sizes?