# Copying element's style width attribute to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a progress bar that is outputted from a webapp program like this:

```
<div id="diskUsageProgressBar">
    <div class="green-bar" style=" width: 1%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have added to the page a much nicer bar like this:

```
<div class="progress xs">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-red diskusgbar" style="width: 1%;"></div>
</div>
```

How could I use javascript (or JQuery) to copy the width value from the first one and paste it into the second one on page load?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why not just apply your classes to the progress bar that's already there?

Comment: I don't have control of the web app's own programming, so I have to work around it...

Comment: You don't need the web app's own programming, you just need to change what classes are applied to its output with jQuery.  eg. `$('#diskUsageProgressBar').addClass('progress xs');`

Comment: I understand, but I'm kinda doing something really complicated so it's not the best option for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery javascript:

```
$('.progress.xss .diskusgbar').css('width', 
    $('#diskUsageProgressBar .green-bar').css('width')
);
```

Comment: jQuery **is** javascript

Comment: Yes I know that! :) But it is also a subset of javascript, so my code will only work if jQuery is included.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$(function(){
   $('.progress-bar-red').attr('style',$('.green-bar').attr('style'));  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only copy the width then you can use native `.width()` method of jquery to get/set value:

```
$('.progress-bar').width($('.green-bar').width());
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$('.progress-bar').width($('.green-bar').width());
```

Answer (score 0):

First, as said in [Is it possible to listen to a "style change" event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157963/is-it-possible-to-listen-to-a-style-change-event)

```
(function() {
var ev = new $.Event('style'),
    orig = $.fn.css;
$.fn.css = function() {
    orig.apply(this, arguments);
    $(this).trigger(ev);
}
})();
```

And then bind it:

```
$('#diskUsageProgressBar > .green-bar').bind('style', function(e) {
 $('.progress.xs > .diskusgbar').css('width', 
  $('#diskUsageProgressBar > .green-bar').css('width')
 );
});
```

Hope it works. Maybe tricky and not so symple if the first bar is in another iframe.