# jQuery watch for style change and then run a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I run certain function when `style` attribute of certain div gets set to `display: none`?

Comment: What about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157963/is-it-possible-to-listen-to-a-style-change-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
        console.log('style changed!');
    });    
});

var target = document.getElementById('myId');
observer.observe(target, { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] });
```

Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

No jQuery is required. However, it is only supported in modern browsers (IE11+).

If you wish to use jQuery, I suppose you could modify the .css function or something.

Fore more information: [Is it possible to listen to a "style change" event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157963/is-it-possible-to-listen-to-a-style-change-event)

Comment: I'm gonna be using Phantom.js and wanted to inject script to a page.
But thanks anyway!