# When a class is shown, add a class to many other elements

Tags: javascript, class, toggle

I have a class called

```
.informations
```

when this class is shown I would love to add a class to some other elements such as

```
#logo
#totale
.submenu
#fp-nav
```

so to change their font color from black to white.
Is there any way to achieve that?

Check this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrz5p79g/)

Comment: can you show some markup and what you have tried?

Comment: @gurvinder372 added the JsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, you can use this extension (found [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-trigger-custom-event-show-hide-element/)):

```
(function($) {
    $.each(['show','hide'], function(i, val) {
        var _org = $.fn[val];
        $.fn[val] = function() {
            this.trigger(val);
            _org.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/wkmzyjL7/).

HTML

```
<div class="informations">
  When this is shown, other elements get white color.
</div>

<div id="logo">
  Logo
</div>

<div id="totale">
  Totale
</div>

<div class="submenu">
  Submenu
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(".informations").on("show", function() {
    $("#logo, #totale, .submenu, #fp-nav").addClass("white-text");
});

setTimeout(function() {
    $(".informations").show();
}, 2000);
```

CSS

```
.white-text {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

.informations {
  display: none;
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/wkmzyjL7/2/), found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157963/is-it-possible-to-listen-to-a-style-change-event)

JavaScript

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
      if(mutationRecord.target.style.display !== "none") {
        console.log('display changed, now visible!');
        $("#logo, #totale, .submenu, #fp-nav").addClass("white-text");
      } else {
        console.log('display changed, now visible!');
        $("#logo, #totale, .submenu, #fp-nav").removeClass("white-text");
      }
    });    
});

observer.observe($(".informations")[0], { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] });

setTimeout(function() {
    $(".informations").show();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".informations").hide();
  }, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks @Arg0n, the problem is that the .informations is a slide and it's not shown after a delay of time, I don't know how to fix your code based on this.

Comment: it's shown as the second slide in a sequence of X slides. it's basically never hidden. When it's displayed on the screen, then I want to addClasses.

Comment: Updated my code for other way to watch for changes in style.