# jQuery: on change style value

Tags: jquery, html, bind

> Html code :

```
<div class="name" style="left:0%"></div>
```

I want if style of *name class* change , alert by **jQuery**

> jQuery code:

```
$('.name').bind('style',function(){
    alert(1);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to listen to a "style change" event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157963/is-it-possible-to-listen-to-a-style-change-event)

Comment: Indeed, if you do not need to support <IE10 then MutationObserver is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/a/20683311/3596962

Comment: thanks, not work me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to consider using `MutationObserver` you'll have to write more code. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var colorsArr = ['red', 'orange', 'gray', 'black', 'blue', 'yellow'];
    $('#btnChangeBackgroundColor').on('click', function () {
    var xColor = colorsArr.shift();
    colorsArr.push(xColor);

    $('.name').css('background-color', xColor);
  });

    $('.name').attr('data-originalstyle', $('.name').attr('style'));

  checkIfStyleChanged();
});

function checkIfStyleChanged() {
    if ($('.name').attr('data-originalstyle') != $('.name').attr('style')) {
   $('.name').attr('data-originalstyle', $('.name').attr('style'));

    $('#lblChanged').html('The Style Changed');
    $('#lblChanged').css('display', '');

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#lblChanged').fadeOut('slow');
    }, 1500);    
  }

  setTimeout(function () {
        checkIfStyleChanged();
    }, 50); 
}
```

See my jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/fictus/6zhqk4b1/