# How to detect the background color changed event Using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi this is my html structure.

```
  <div class="test-class" style="background-color: red;" >1</div>
  <div class="test-class" style="background-color: blue;" >1</div>
  <div class="test-class" style="background-color: green;" >1</div>
```

Here on first page load the background-color of test-class come randomly .

i want to run  an function when the background color of test-class is changed . How to do this ?

> Edit

so from [Is it possible to listen to a "style change" event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157963/is-it-possible-to-listen-to-a-style-change-event) this question i got  a solution

```
(function() {
    var ev = new $.Event('style'),
        orig = $.fn.css;
    $.fn.css = function() {
        $(this).trigger(ev);
        return orig.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})();

$('.test-class').bind('style', function(e) {
    console.log( $(this).attr('style') );
});
```

But please help to apply this answer .
i want to alert the content of that div and it's color when it's background-color is changed .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to listen to a "style change" event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157963/is-it-possible-to-listen-to-a-style-change-event)

Answer (score 1):

If some javascript changes the background color, can you just call the function after changing the background?

Comment: Yeah, that would be the best way to do it. Silly to do it any other way. You'd have to store the original value in a variable and compare it to the possibly new, current value at set intervals... not worth the headache.

Comment: what happen if we can't detect which event make change in background colour ? or if the external jquery file make change in div's background .?