# Is it possible to detect when an attribute value changes to equal a specific value, and not just detect that it changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been looking into ways to detect when the value of an attribute changes to equal a specific value. MutationObserver seems to indicate only that the attribute value has changed as opposed to checking to see that is has changed and is equal to a specific value.

I have click event that runs a setTimeout of 200ms to call a function for a radial progress indicator. The value of the HTML attribute for the indicator counts up from 0 to 100 after the click and setTimeout. When it's complete, the HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="radial-progress" data-progress="100">
```

Is there a way that I can fire another function or run some other code when **and only when** data-progress == 100?

Here is the script:

```
$("#someID").on("click", function(event){
     event.preventDefault();

     // Load-progress counter //
     window.loadProgress = function() {
          $('.loadProgress .radial-progress').attr('data-progress', Math.floor(1 * 100));
     }
     setTimeout(window.loadProgress, 200);

     // Run some other code when data-progress == 100
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a workaround trick by adding some arbitrary style to you div, some style that would not affect how it looks.
Assign only this style when `data-progress="100"`

```
div.radial-progress[data-progress="100"] {
  some-style:whatever;
}
```

and then use [MutationObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157963/is-it-possible-to-listen-to-a-style-change-event) to monitor the style change.

Comment: Can MutationObserver detect a style change though, especially if it's not inline? I'm unsure of how this would work.