# How to notify when a table in html is resized??

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

This is what I'm trying. unable to generate alert with text "resized". Does resize event on table work?? If it doesn't how can i achieve it??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
<script  src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){ 
  $("#btn").click(function(e){
            $("#normal").css("width", "1200px");
        });
   });
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(){
        alert("resized");}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center" >
    <div style="float:left;">
        <div style="height:100px; width: 50px; float:'left'">
            <button style="height:30px; width: 150px; float:'left'" id="btn">Click</button>
        </div>
         <table id="normal" width="75%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="float:left;" onresize="myFunction()">
            <tr><th>header</th><th>header</th><th>header</th></tr>
            <tr><td class="left">cell</td><td>cell</td><td class="right">cell</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="left">cell</td><td>cell</td><td class="right">cell</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="left bottom">cell</td><td class="bottom">cell</td><td class="bottom right">cell</td></tr>                                                                    
        </table>
    </div></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `table` elements don't raise a resize event. If you want this behaviour you would need to `trigger()` a custom event when you change the size of the table, or just call the function manually.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`window.resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize) event. You don't resize a table: You resize the window, which may just happen to adjust the flow on the webpage, including your table.

If you're going to be resizing it, with other means than the window, check out the `MutationObserver` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20683311/4875631).

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
        console.log('style changed!');
        //Check if resized here
    });    
});

var target = document.getElementById('normal');
observer.observe(target, { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] });

console.log('After 2 seconds, the style will change');
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#normal").css("width", "1200px");
}, 2000);
```

```css
#normal
{
  width: 200px;
}

.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="normal"></div>
```

Comment: The issue OP has though, is that he's resizing the `table` element only, not the window at all.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah, I saw him modifying the DOM after I answered. I posted a followup.