# Trigger event before change class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are many buttons and links that would let me quit one page. Before leaving this page to another, I want to ask something to the user, and then, just quit this page.

In our app, the "leave this page" is just like `<canvas class="show"></canvas>` to `<canvas class=""></canvas>` and showing another canvas. Others has done this. My goal is to detect whether the `class="show"` is removed or not.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157963/is-it-possible-to-listen-to-a-style-change-event), and so on. I'm quite junior, do not understand what they really mean or just don't know how to implement it in my question.

Please help, the more specific example list below:

```js
$('body').on('class_change_event', () => {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: 'If you close without saving, your changes will discarded.',
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: "Save"
    })
    // After the user choose, do the original jobs
})
```

```css
div.demo { 
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<div class="demo">
    <canvas class="load show"></canvas>
    <canvas class="load"></canvas>
    <canvas class="load"></canvas>
</div>

<a href="https://www.google.com">go to Google</a>
<a href="index.html">back to index</a>
<input type="button" value="Clear canvas" />
```

Note

- Even when user click `button` or `a` will cause `class="show"` changed.
- I'm not sure if it's right to append event onto $('body')

Comment: Do you mean like one of the dialogs that pops up that says `Do you really want to leave without saving your changes?` when you are editing something and try to close out?

Comment: The accepted answers on the questions you linked are old. Take a look at newer answers using mutations in those same questions.

Comment: @Jodast YES!  For original goal, if the user answer OK(YES), it will save the canvas, and also, both of YES or NO will switch to another canvas(which means toggleClass to another one)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent a user from leaving the page, you want to use the `beforeunload` event. This will cause the browser to prompt the user if they really want to leave the page. However, if you're using a SPA, you'll need to tie into your framework's routing to show a prompt when it changes routes.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) { ... });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: Or the jQuery equivalent, `$(window).on('beforeunload', function() { ... });`

Comment: I'm not sure it is a good idea. There are still many buttons will change that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I got you. I guess that is what you need. We create observer that is looks 
 for class changes in target elements. In **all** elements with class **.load**. See comments in script too.

```js
let views = [...document.querySelectorAll(".load")];
views.forEach(view => {

  // create an observer instance that will look for class changes
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      // we only need to detect class changes
      if (mutation.attributeName !== 'class') {
        return false;
      }
      // exact node which classList has been changed
      let el = mutation.target
      if (el.classList.contains("show")) {
        confirmLeave();
      }
    });
  });

  // configuration of the observer. We need to detect "class" attribute changes 
  var config = {
    attributes: true
  };

  // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
  observer.observe(view, config);
})

// Let's test our observer
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('.load').classList.add('show')
}, 2000)

function confirmLeave() {
  // this string is just to check and show you can remove it later and use your script below
  document.querySelector('.text').textContent = 'Element got "show" class!';
  /*swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: 'If you close without saving, your changes will discarded.',
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: "Save"
  })*/
}
```

```css
.load {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.load.show {
  background-color: red;
}

.text {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="load"></div>

<div class="text"></div>
```

Comment: In my case, there are many methods(other people and other libraries did) will cause the class 'show' toggled. My question about your answer is that which method or event will trigger leaveView()..?

Comment: See ny answer above. I have edited it so think it is what you looking for.