# Set style change event listener in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

My div looks something like this:

```
<div tabindex="0" role="button" id="profile-pic" style="background-image: "Some url";"></div>
```

The background image will be updated based on some criteria. I want to set listener to the style property and listen to background image change. Is it possible?

Comment: Read about [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: Note that the style attribute change (that MutationObserver will be able to observe) doesn't necessarily means the actual background-image change. If the property is set to an invalid value, or if some CSS rules took predescedence (e.g with `!important` keyword), then MutationObserver will report false positives. In the same way, if a CSS rule is applied and takes predescedence over the style attribute's rule, then the MutationObserver will miss it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Then code example:

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
    console.log('style changed!');
  });    
});

var target = document.getElementById('myId');

observer.observe(target, { 
  attributes: true, 
  attributeFilter: ['style'] 
});
```

Note:  this only works with inline styles(any changing of styles), not when the style changes as a consequence of class change or @media change
This is a answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20683311/3344953

Comment: Is there a way to remove the observer before setting?  To make sure its not set multiple times

Answer (score 2):

It's *possible* with MutationObserver, but it's a somewhat odd thing to do:

```js
console.log('Script start');
const div = document.querySelector('div');

const o = new MutationObserver(() => {
  console.log('style changed');
});
o.observe(div, { attributes: true, attributeFilter: ["style"] });

setTimeout(() => {
  div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/34932d3e923ffad9a4a1423e30b1d9fc?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1)';
}, 500);
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" role="button" id="profile-pic" style="background-image: 'Some url';">xx</div>
```

It would make a lot more sense for the function that makes the style change to call other functions that need to know that the change happened.