# Click event of a MODAL

Tags: jquery

How do I capture the click event of a modal when closing it without having to use jquery
similar to  this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/xfxstudios/36zf5tu8/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#myModal").modal("show");

    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal("hide");
    });
    $("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            alert("Esta accion se ejecuta al cerrar el modal")
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, this looks like an angularJs problem, so you should probably retag it.

Comment: Do you have Angular code that creates the modal? Please share that in that case. Right now, we have no idea what toolkit you use to create the modal (Bootstrap, Angular Material, etc.)

Comment: if bootstrap, you can disable closing by backdrop click or esc key with this ` data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" ` and add event on-click or ngClick on close button and close "times (X)"

Comment: Question seems a little ambiguous. On first read, I thought you were asking for how to create functionality without using jQuery library.

Comment: When using jQuery `.on()` you need to pass an actual event type in the first param, example: `click`, `hover`, etc. You are passing `hidden.bs.modal` which is not a valid event and will not ever be triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your modal is closed, then it's display attribute is set to none. If you want to do something on closing the modal without using `hidden.bs.modal`, then one of the solution is to implement a style change listener.

Add a style change listener which listens to changes in styles of the modal. To that style change listener, specify what `div` you want to listen(in your case, it's the modal div) and the style attribute of that div(in your case, it's `display` attribute).

So whenever the display of the modal changes to none, run the function you want.

For more info, refer this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55590917/5913737