# triggering javascript on css visibility change

Tags: javascript, css

Using JavaScript to change CSS visibility is trivial

```
element.style.visibility = 'visible'
element.style.display = 'block'
```

but, is it possible to go the other way, that is, trigger JS when CSS visibility changes? For example

```css
#element {
   visibility: hidden;
   display: none;
}

#element::target {
   visibility: visible;
   display: block;
}
```

When a user clicks on `element`, I want `aFunction()` to fire with access to info about the element's DOM properties. I am assuming that is not possible but asking just in case…

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55590763/set-style-change-event-listener-in-javascript?

Comment: Not sure I understand - is there a reason for not sensing the click event and firing the function?

Comment: @evolutionbox, thanks for the link to the `MutationObserver` question. It almost (but not quite) does what I want but, on the other hand, I learned something new :)

@a-haworth I was not using a click even but instead using the CSS pseudoclass `:target` to change visibility, and wanted to fire a function when the visibility changed.

Anyway, have decided to implement a different approach. Thanks all. Am closing the question.