# Cypress how can I check if the background changes in a div

Tags: javascript, html, testing, cypress

I have a div in which I load dynamic image depending if the user clicks on a button.

```
<div style="background-image: url('myimage.png')"></div>
```

so far this is my test:

```
cy.get('label').first().click();

cy.get('.bg-cover').should('have.css', 'background-image');
```

But how can I check if the background src changes.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157963/is-it-possible-to-listen-to-a-style-change-event

Comment: Have you tried `.should('have.css', 'background-image', "url('myimage.png')");`?

Comment: @dork the image url can be dynamic, that is why I need to check wether the image exists and the url changes on click

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure you already resolved this, but I leave my solution for other

```js
cy.get('.bg-cover')
  .should('have.css', 'background-image')
  .and('include', 'myimage.png')
```