# jQuery - How to write a plugin that will automatically call on future elements

Tags: jquery

A simple plugin

```
jQuery.fn.cleanHouse = function() {
    //do stuff
}

$('.dirty').cleanHouse();
```

How can we make sure future elements $('.dirty') will automatically call cleanHouse() ?

I'm looking solution do something with the plugin itself

Comment: how will future elements come to fruit? this dictates how you might create your own trigger (of a custom event) which you could bind live() to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to achieve this. The only way the plugin can get called in the future is through an event.

Answer (score 0):

is jquery's live() function what you need?

http://api.jquery.com/live/

or this

[jQuery - Fire event if CSS class changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with .live() is that you can only use it in connection with an event, and there is no built-in event that fires when you add elements to the DOM.

But here's a detailed explanation on how you make that happen with a custom "create" event: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-create-event/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a combination, try something like this:

```
$.fn.cleanHouse = function() {
    return $(this).live('click', function() { 
        //do stuff
    });
}
$('.dirty').cleanHouse();
```