# Is there an event that fires when an element's `class` attribute changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<ul>` element on my page with a few children.  A `class` attribute will be added to these children at some point,

Before

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

After

```
<ul>
  <li class='classname'>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to bind to an event that will fire whenever the `li` element's class changes, so I can handle it accordingly.  Is there such an event?

Comment: How are you changing the li's class?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that there is some way to bind to a [DOM Mutation event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents), but I've never actually done this myself, and don't know even if it's supported cross-browser.

Instead, just find the code which actually makes the change and insert your handler there.

```
function something() {
    $('li').addClass('classname');
    doSomething(); // <-- here
}
```

Or, if you want to be able to break it apart and use events, you can trigger custom events with jQuery.

```
function something() {
    $('li').addClass('classname').trigger('classChange');
}

// elsewhere:
$('li').bind('classChange', function () { ... });
```

Comment: All - Just a note: [DOM mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationEvent) were deprecated fairly soon after this answer was written in 2011. Instead, see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612024/event-trigger-on-a-class-change) -- basically, use a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Answer (score 0):

I Think you need to see this post

[jQuery - Fire event if CSS class changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed)

rather i hate jquery and i will search it on pure javascript

Regards

Comment: You haven't done any big projects yet, this is why you'd never had to use jQuery.

Comment: @ Hossein i did many big projects and for each i use my own framework mScript and from time to time i add new features to my framework from my new experience // i only use jquery when i'm in too tight schedule and i face new issues not covered in my framework

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are going to change the elements, you can use custom events and custom getters to simulate a 'real' event.