# Run a jquery function whenever its div parent container class changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to run the function below whenever its div parent container `<div class="section">...</div>` becomes "active" e.g. `<div class="section active">...</div>`

```
  $(".skills-grid__col").each(function () {
      var left = $(this).data('left');
      $(this).animate({
          opacity: 1,
          left: left
      }, 1200);
  });

<div class="section">
  <div class="skills-grid__col"></div>
  <div class="skills-grid__col"></div>
</div>
```

What kind of event should I use in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [event trigger on class change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612024/event-trigger-on-class-change)

Comment: Much better is to trigger some event from the code that actually changes class.

Comment: If you have access to the event which makes the container "active", put your code in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really a lot you can do with events if you want to support old browsers.

If dropping support for IE10 is OK, then you can use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) which will be notified when the element changes :

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  if ($yourElement.hasClass('active')) {
     // do things
  }
});
observer.observe($yourElement[0], {attributes: true});
```

If you can't drop IE10, and assuming you don't want to periodically check the element, you'd have to hook the part where the class changes, which is usually the best solution. Of course you could also write a shim by periodically checking the class if `window.MutationObserver`  is `undefined`.

Comment: I plan to support IE9+, but thanks for the possible solution. Seems like hooking the function to the event where the class changes is the only appropriate solution in this case. Thanks.