# How to call a Bootstrap class into JavaScript using (document.get element by class)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, dom

How to call a bootstrap class into JavaScript using the HTML DOM `getElementsByClassName()` method?

for eg:-

```
document.getElementByClass=("has-error");
```

I need a the text box to turn into green if the data is valid and to red if the data is invalid using Bootstrap classes `has-success` and `has-error`.

Comment: bootstrap is already setting these classes; just use CSS to apply styles

Comment: bootstrap has already written some styles for this class i need to call this styles directly.

Comment: use CSS to override bootstrap's styles; javascript is not necessary here. include your styles for these classes after `bootstrap.css` in a separate stylesheet.

Comment: i can get you. you are asking me to add a style in css and asking me to call that file into that                                                                                                                  but in bootstrap there is a class for this function why should i write in seperate css if it there

Comment: use angular `ng-class` .. see docs

Answer (score 0):

See the bootstrap will do this any have I will show you the code based on your example.

```
function addClassNameListener(elemId, callback) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
    var lastClassName = elem.className;
    window.setInterval( function() {   
       var className = elem.className;
        if (className !== lastClassName) {
            callback();   
            lastClassName = className;
        }
    },10);
}
```

This topic already discussed in [event trigger on class change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612024/event-trigger-on-class-change)
. Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/RaguNS/Lt99puLz/1/