# If this div has this class, hide another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to hide the button **ONLY** if a specific div (.variable-item-3) has the class "selected".

The class "selected" is added when the li is clicked.

```js
if($('.variable-item-3').hasClass('selected')) {
    $('.button').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="variable-item-1">Option 1</li>
    <li class="variable-item-2">Option 2</li>
    <li class="variable-item-3 selected">Option 3</li>
</ul>

<button type="submit" class="button">Add to cart</button>
```

Comment: How about just hiding the element when the li is clicked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event trigger on a class change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612024/event-trigger-on-a-class-change)

Comment: Not sure why we need `selected` here when the button has to be hidden on every click on `li`, as it says that `selected` will be added on clicking an `li`.

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz It can't be onclick because if the user selects another option, the button would stay hidden.

Comment: @Ejaz Only if Option 3 is selected then hide the button.

Answer (score 3):

You need to perform the test after you change the `selected` class. You're just running it once when the page is loaded, it won't automatically run again when the class changes.

You can use the `.toggle()` function with a boolean argument to make the visibility depend on a test.

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  $("li").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  $(".button").toggle(!$('.variable-item-3').hasClass('selected'));
});
```

```css
li.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="variable-item-1">Option 1</li>
    <li class="variable-item-2">Option 2</li>
    <li class="variable-item-3 selected">Option 3</li>
</ul>

<button type="submit" class="button">Add to cart</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using javascript to add the `.selected` class, it's probably easier to use the javascript solutions suggested in the other answers. However, if you prefer using CSS (I personally prefer using CSS to Javascript whenever possible) and if the div you care about comes *before* the button you care about then you can actually just use CSS.

```
.variable-item-3.selected ~ .button {
  display: none;
}
```

This assumes that `.button` and `.selected` are siblings. It gets more complicated if the two aren't siblings but it's still possible as long as an ancestor of `.button` is a sibling of `.selected`. In that case it would look something like this:

```
.variable-item-3.selected ~ div .button {
  display: none;
}
```

If the HTML isn't structured so that either of these will work, then you'll need to use one of the other solutions that does it with javascript.

Comment: I wished this worked but unfortunately it didn't for me. The button and div aren't siblings.