# Conditionally add class to element based on other element status/class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide an image after I scroll down my page. When scrolling my `header` gets a class `fl-theme-builder-header-scrolled`. My image div has a class `hiding-image` and I want to add a class `image-off` when the `fl-theme-builder-header-scrolled` class shows up in the `header`.
This is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($( 'header' ).hasClass( 'fl-theme-builder-header-scrolled' )) {
    $( '.hiding-image' ).toggleClass( 'image-off' );
} 
});
```

but this doesn't work. Any advice? Thx.

Comment: You should execute your if statement on the scroll event

Comment: What is adding the `fl-theme-builder-header-scrolled` class?

Comment: To add to what @ErikPhilips said, I think the best approach is to put your logic where the ```fl-theme-builder-header-scrolled``` is getting toggled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work doing this:

```
(function($){
  $(function(){
    var headerThemer = $( '.fl-builder-content[data-type=header]' ).eq(0);
    $(window).on( 'scroll.fl-theme-builder-header-scrolled', function(){
        if ( headerThemer.hasClass('fl-theme-builder-header-scrolled') ) {
            $('.hiding-image').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('.hiding-image').show();
        }
    });
  })
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code only runs once after the document ready, as soon as the page loads. So if the header doesn't have the `fl-theme-builder-header-scrolled` class and only gets added later, your code will not run again.

You need a a mutation Observer.
Check this thread: [Event trigger on a class change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612024/event-trigger-on-a-class-change?lq=1)

Alternatively you can do as @Brewal is saying, putting the code evaluation on the scroll event. Although be careful so you don't run the code every time the scroll event is triggered since it can slow your website performance, specially on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($( 'header' ).hasClass( 'fl-theme-builder-header-scrolled' )) {
   $( '.hiding-image' ).toggleClass( 'image-off' );
 }

});
```

Comment: Produce your code in a sandbox like codepen.io or jsfiddle so I can take a look at why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, I think the best approach would be to find where the `fl-theme-builder-header-scrolled` class is already being controlled.

However, If you really would want to put the logic in a separate area, you can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(window).scroll(function () { //attach to window scroll event

    if ($('header').hasClass('fl-theme-builder-header-scrolled') && !$('.hiding-image').hasClass('image-off')) {
        $('.hiding-image').addClass('image-off'); //add class only if it does not already exist;
    } else {
        if ($('.hiding-image').hasClass('image-off')) {
            $('.hiding-image').removeClass('image-off'); //remove class
        }
    }

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check condition like this:

```
`$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($( 'header' ).hasClass( 'fl-theme-builder-header-scrolled' )) 
    {
        $( '.hiding-image' ).addClass( 'image-off' );
    }
    else
    {
        $( '.hiding-image' ).removeClass( 'image-off' );
    }
});`
```