# Check the class status of an element at any point during browsing using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element which i know isn't going to have a class on it at page load, but i know it will at some point. Now what are my options of keeping track of the classes added and removed from the element, by other methods using addClass() and removeClass()? I'm using jQuery but would be happy with a vanilla JavaScript solution.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed?

Comment: nice i didnt know you could put a trigger on the class change its awesome ;)

Comment: You have to raise the event yourself when you change css classes OR get the JS that the thread discusses and see if it will work. You could do it by altering the jQuery library (.addClass, .removeClass, .css etc) too.

Comment: but you should NEVER alter jquery :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no event of "class added", you will have to keep an eye on the classes you add to elements.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1950052/601179) answer

Answer (score -1):

in vanilla you can use

```
document.getElementById('divId').className;
```

or in jquery

```
$('#divId').attr('class');
```

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. I need to keep track of the classes on an element, they could be added at any point from any piece of code.

Comment: Not sure but are you saying that you want to keep an array of all the classes an element has had?