# Wait until HTML elements gets a class then do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am waiting for the document.ready event in order to do something on my page.

Alas some other script, which I cannot change, has not worked its magic yet once my script is called. Hence, jquery selection on the class name fails as the class does not yet exist in the DOM.

This is why I want tell my function to listen until an element gets a certain class, then do something with it.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you control this other script? Can't you call your code as a callback of the other code?

Comment: or get the other script to fire a custom event

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed

Comment: @j08691 Alas I do not. Edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could trigger some event once you added the class.

Example:

```
$('#ele').addClass('theClass');
$(document).trigger('classGiven')


$(document).bind('classGiven',function(){
    //do what you need
});
```

Answer (score 17):

Something like this (pseudo code) :

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
   if (element.className=='someclass') {
       //run some other function 
       goDoMyStuff();
       clearInterval(timer);
   }
}, 200);
```

or listen for the element to be inserted:

```
function flagInsertedElement(event) {
   var el=event.target;
}
document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', flagInsertedElement, false);
```

jQuery version:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    if (e.target.className=='someclass') { 
        goDoMyStuff();
    }
});
```

There's also the [liveQuery](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs) plugin:

```
$("#future_element").livequery(function(){
    //element created
});
```

Or if this is a regular event handler, delegated events with jQuery's on();

Comment: Got three downvotes on that, but a simple setInterval like that does not use much resources and works just fine, but should have some sort of ending if the class was never found, like a timeout function that clears the interval after a couple of seconds. The jQuery funcion for listening to DOM node inserted is probably the best way to do it, but unless the handler is removed that will just keep on going, checking all inserted elements for the className, which in my opinion is worse than having a setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if I got your question wrong but why not just doing something plain as this on document.ready ? :

```
$("#myelement").addClass('myclass');

if($("#myelement").hasClass('myclass')) {
    alert('do stuff here');
}
```

Comment: I do not add the element with this class. It gets added by another script. And I want to catch that change and afterwards do some magic on it.

Comment: so maybe better would be add callback in that another script if possible?