# jQuery on class removing event

Tags: jquery, html

Well, I got something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="main" class="underline" >Hello</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('div').live('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("underline");
});​
```

https://jsfiddle.net/VYukS/

I have to run some function on event when div class was removed, and I haven't got any permisions to edit functions that adding / removing class from div.

How can I catch that event when class is removing?

'click' event was used only as an example, so that class can be removen not only on the clicking

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Fire event if CSS class changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed) (in particular, the second answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1950199/444991)

Comment: In future, please don't *just* include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should standalone from any other resource; consider what'd happen if jsFiddle went down in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such event. But you can do simpler:

```
$('div').live('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("underline")
    if ($(this).hasClass("underline")) {
        alert("added");
    } else {
        alert("removed");
    }
});​
```

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/VYukS/1/

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: `live()` is deprecated. Try to use jquery newest version

```
$('body').on('click', 'div#main', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("underline");
    // to check the class presence
   if($(this).hasClass('underline'))
     alert('no class');
   else
     alert('has underline');
});
```

or use [delegate()](https://api.jquery.com/delegate)

```
$('body').delegate('div#main', 'click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("underline");
});
```

Comment: Have you opened JSFiddle link? OP uses JQuery 1.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
     $('div').unbind('click', function(){
       $(this).toggleClass("underline");
     });
```