# How do I track/troubleshoot a <div> or <class> attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image-gallery

I'm troubleshooting a scrolling gallery with standard left and right navigation arrows.  I'm wondering if there is a way to track when a specific div or class tag is modified upon loading the webpage.  My problem is that

```
<class="next browse right disabled">
```

is being applied to my right arrow when it should be

```
<class="next browse right">
```

It is a heavily modified jquery-tools scrolling gallery that someone else wrote and I'm just not sure how to approach this.  Any advice/help is appreciated!

Comment: If you feel it is too much for you to debug, simply remove the undesired class in a timeout. For us to do help you do it, you will need to provide complete div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery does not have any baked in event that can help you intercept addition/ removal of a class to div. You can at anytime use [jQuery hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) to see whether a particular class is applied or not.

> $('#mySelector').hasClass('right')  //returns a boolean

You can take advantage of [chrome dev tools breakpoint debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) if you are performing these actions via javascript.

Finally, if you insist on capturing class change, then you must raise your own event. Please see this question:

[jQuery - Fire event if CSS class changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed)

Comment: I ended up using a combination of the methods you described to me and got it working!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works:

```
$('next.browse.right.disabled').removeClass('disabled');
```

or

```
$('next.browse.right').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Maybe DOM Breakpoints in the Chrome devtools would help?

Comment: Hi, I've tried those but no success.  What I really want to do is figure out what logic/expression is causing that wrong class to be applied so I can fix it from there.

Comment: Have you searched something like addClass("disabled") in the jquery source?