# Call a function when particular div class has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, fotorama

I working on project in which i m used the slider and slider has change the class of particular after interval and show the image according the classes have been changed So there is my need "call" a jquery function when class has changed

Comment: show your code to understand your problem

Comment: Show us your code at Jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might looking for this:

[Jquery fire event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed) , you should improve your question better with codes to next ppl cming here can understand what you have and what you do to solve.

Comment: thanks @Guerra its working now i have add function fotorama when new classes added ..........

Answer (score 0):

Why not call the jquery function within the actual slider's event handler?  It sounds like the slider could be responsible for both the div class change and the appropriate "class change" response code.