# jQuery attach a click handler after div is created

Tags: jquery

I'm pretty sure that the answer isn't that difficult, but I'm not sure where to look for it.

I would like to attach a jQuery event handler when a div gets created. For example:

```
$('#somediv').click(function(){
    //do something
});
```

But... `#somediv` doesn't exist. Because of some AJAX loads it will. So what I need is something like.

```
$('#somediv').whenImcreated(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        //do something
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a delegated event:

```
$(document).on('click', '#somediv', function(){
    //do something
});
```

Note that while `document` as the primary selector will work, for best performance you should make it the closest parent element of `#somediv` which is present in the DOM on `document.ready`.

Comment: A good start, but OP asked when it was *created*, not when it was clicked. Do you have an event for when the div 'comes  to life'??

Comment: I suggest you read and understand the question. While the OP says they want to know when the element is created it's obvious they are trying to attach an event handler after it has been added to the DOM. If you really want to have an event fired when an element is created, use a MutationObserver, something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19401707/519413

Answer (score 2):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).on('click', '#somediv', function(){ ... });
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```