# How to bind classChange in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to bind classChange in jQuery?
I need to when one class change, change other class.

I have this function, but this functon run only one time at the web-site load.
I need to make a event listener. Can someone help me?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
function switchClass() {
    if($("#sidebar").hasClass('pin-top')){
         $('#sidebar').removeClass('s2');
    }   
    else if($("#sidebar").hasClass('pinned')) {
         $('#sidebar').addClass('s2');
    } 
}
```

Comment: When are you calling the function `switchClass` ? And when you need to invoke this function ?

Comment: You can just call `switchClass()` everytime.

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401633/how-to-fire-an-event-on-class-change-using-jquery/31859060#31859060

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "class change" event. On modern browsers, you can use [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for changes to attributes (including `class`) on elements, and respond to those. On *slightly* older browsers you can use a library that emulates mutation observers with the old, deprecated mutation events. (Just search for "mutation observer emulation".) On older browsers than that, you have to poll.

```
// Watch for changes
var ob = new MutationObserver(function() {
  // The class *may* have changed, handle it
});
ob.observe($("#sidebar")[0], {
  attributes: true
});
```

Here's a mutation observer example:

```js
// Once a second, add or remove the 'foo' class, Just so we have
// something to respond to. Stop after 10.
var counter = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  $("#sidebar").toggleClass("foo");
  if (++counter >= 10) {
    $("<p>Done</p>").appendTo(document.body);
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 1000);

// Watch for changes
var ob = new MutationObserver(function() {
  $("<p>").html("It " + ($("#sidebar").hasClass("foo") ? "does" : "does not") + " have the foo class").appendTo(document.body);
});
ob.observe($("#sidebar")[0], {
  attributes: true
});
```

```css
.foo {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">I'm the 'sidebar' element</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Fantastic solution.. @T.J. Crowder.. :)