# Detecting class change without setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, mutation-observers

I have a `div` that has additional classes added to it programmatically. How can I detect the class name change without using this `setInterval` implementation?

```
setInterval(function() {
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('original')[0];
    if (elem.classList.contains("added")) { detected(); }
}, 5500);
```

MutationObserver?

Comment: Can you fire an event when you change the class?  Or do you want to detect the class change on a client that isn't doing the changing?   ie. the document has changed?   You may be able to do that with a push update.

Comment: This is what MutationObserver with attributeFilter option is for: [How to react to a specific style attribute change with mutation observers?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39024295) - replace `style` with `class`.

Comment: I'm not doing the changing... My code is injected via chrome extension

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). It's quite [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=mutationobserver) nowadays.

```js
var e = document.getElementById('test')
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (event) {
  console.log(event)   
})

observer.observe(e, {
  attributes: true, 
  attributeFilter: ['class'],
  childList: false, 
  characterData: false
})

setTimeout(function () {
  e.className = 'hello'
}, 1000)
```

```html
<div id="test">
</div>
```