# How to blur a div when a class is added inside another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I have a mega menu element with class `.dropdownOpen` activated when it is hovered. Meanwhile I have to change CSS on a completely separate div outside the header div

I have to add this CSS when `.dropdownOpen` is acivated by JS to

```
#theme-page {
    filter: blur(8px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
}
```

What could be the best solution? I tried pure CSS but I was not able to do it.

**EDIT:**

Here -was- a live example website.

When hovering on Mega menu element, there is a class added `.dropdownOpen` just after `.has-mega-menu` here:

```
<li id="menu-item-1068" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-mega-menu"><a class="menu-item-link js-smooth-scroll" href="/4" aria-haspopup="true">Mega menu</a>
```

If that class is added I need to blur the whole div `#theme-page` which is located way more down below.

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42121795/9192223

Comment: Please post complete code including JS & Html

Comment: @RiteshKhandekar I added a live example website link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added a tag with `jQuery` so we can use it and do:

```
jQuery('.has-mega-menu').hover(() => jQuery('#theme-page').addClass('blur'), () => jQuery('#theme-page').removeClass('blur'))
```

and add some css for our `blur` class:

```
.blur {
    filter: blur(8px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @buszmen working! btw how can I add a small delay to it?

Comment: You can use css `animation` and `keyframes` to create 3 steps: 0%, 99% with no blur and 100% with full blur. The animation duration will be your delay. If you want to smooth out the blurring, just change 99% to something smaller and play with the duration.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `MutationObserver` to detect the class change.

You can read more about `MutationObserver` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```js
function addclass() {
  document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.toggle("dropdownOpen");
}

(function() {
  var e = document.getElementById("dropdown"); // the maga menu element
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(event) {
    let otherDiv = document.getElementById("otherDiv");
    if (/.*dropdownOpen.*/.test(e.className)) {
      otherDiv.classList.add("theme-page");
    } else {
      otherDiv.classList.remove("theme-page");
    }
  });
  observer.observe(e, {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ["class"],
    childList: false,
    characterData: false
  });
})();
```

```css
.dropdownOpen {
  background-color: red;
}
.theme-page {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown">Dropdown</div>
<div id="otherDiv">Other div</div>
<button onclick="addclass()">Add Class</button>
```

Comment: I tried to edit this but got a console error and removed it :(

Comment: I do not remember anymore, but it was something about none existing node. The solution that Buszmen provided works very well in my case.