# How to track DOM modification by JS or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my website, after loading a page, CSS height is adding to the `DOM` and I am unable to find from where it was modified. Is there any way to debug it?

Below is the demo example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .div { border: 1px solid; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="div"> <b>hello</b> </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.div').css("height", "200px");
                $('body > div').css("height", "200px");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

DOM can modify from any file and in any way. How can I debug it on a large website?

Thank you.

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi I think you missed these bits of the question:  *below is the demo **example**.* and *DOM can modify from any file and in any way*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting class change without setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121565/detecting-class-change-without-setinterval)

Comment: Use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: If you wanna try a more modern aproach try https://alpinejs.dev/. There is a big hipe about it recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can observe all changes in the DIV element by using MutationObserver.

```js
let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
     console.log(mutation.attributeName);
  });
});

observer.observe($('#test')[0], {childList:true, attributes:true}); 

//test  
$('#test').height("50px")      
setTimeout(function(){$('#test').height("100px")},3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord

Comment: How will I get the JS file path if it was changed from a different file?

Comment: maybe you can put a breakpoint on the .resize() function for the div, and expect that the offending file revels itself in the call stack. Just a wild guess...

Comment: Yes, resize browser width and debugger works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to any resize on your element by `ResizeObserver`

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.div').css("height", "200px");
            $('body > div').css("height", "200px");
        });

        
        new ResizeObserver((e) => {
            console.log("cahnged");

        }).observe($('.div')[0])
```

```css
.div {
            border: 1px solid;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
<div class="div"> <b>hello</b> </div>
```

Comment: I want to know from which JS file, It was changed?

Comment: @26vivek I don't think you can get Origin or caller of event unless you send extra data when changing the height

Comment: my problem is I am unable to find who is adding height to the dom in my website.

Comment: You can find it by trial and error. exclude some js file and see the result and keep going to find it

Comment: @26vivek Which IDE do you use? If you are using visual studio put `debugger` and see the call stack

Comment: I use phpstorm.

Comment: Can you put your code in stackblitz to better explore that?

Comment: @26vivek Did you figure this out? I am in the same boat. I have a 3rd party JS file loaded on my web site modifying my DOM and I can't tell which one is doing it