# Do something (go to slide) if class is added - lightslider

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm using lightslider. I'm trying to reach to the first slide when you hit the last ine but I cannot use loop for layout reasons. I added a last li after the dynamic gallery and added and if li is active go to slide, but doesn't work and neither returns errors. Any idea what's wrong?

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      var sliderhome = jQuery('#slider-home').lightSlider({
    controls: true,
    prevHtml: '<span>PREV</span>',
    nextHtml: '<span>NEXT</span>',
    loop: true,
            pause: 5000,
            item: 1,
    enableDrag: false,
            mode: "slide",
            onSliderLoad: function() {
            jQuery('#slider-home').removeClass('cS-hidden');
            }
});
  });


if (jQuery("#lasthome").hasClass("active")) {
               sliderhome.goToSlide(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .focus() method?

```
sliderHome.focus();
```

or

```
$('#slider-home').focus();
```

Comment: where should I place it?

Comment: Within your if condition, as you want to go to slide if class is added. Simple!!

Comment: Does that worked for you? If yes then accept the answer :)

Comment: It didn't work. What I found out is that I need to use MutationObserver, like this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401633/how-to-fire-an-event-on-class-change-using-jquery

Comment: I could detect class changes and do something but I need to detect some specific change: if div has .class1.class2 do something. If class2 disappears, go back

Comment: You can use something like this to check if div has class or not:
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-has-a-particular-class/

Comment: that works if element has both classes, but not if it's added later