# On Class Change, Update HTML Attribute Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

The WordPress theme I'm using adds two logos, a dark one when the site loads, and a lighter one when the sticky nav is activated upon scroll. When the sticky nav is active the class 'scrolled' is added to the containing div, 'scroll_header_top_area'.

The code below works if I've already scrolled down the page and the sticky nav is active and I refresh the page, but it doesn't switch out the logos dynamically when scrolling.

I've seen the suggestions to use [MutationObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401633/how-to-fire-an-event-on-class-change-using-jquery) but I'm afraid I can't understand the example or how to use it here.

How would I change this code to make the change dynamic based upon whether the 'scrolled' class is active.

```
if  ( $j('.scroll_header_top_area').hasClass('scrolled'))  {

    $j(".q_logo img").attr("src","path_to_image/light.png");
}

else {
    $j(".q_logo img").attr("src","path_to_image/dark.png");
}
```

Comment: is the above JS enclosed in something like `$('#myDiv').on('classChange', function({})` ?

Comment: No it's not - is that what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need an event handler. This will handle a scrolling event.

```
$j(".q_logo img").attr("src","path_to_img/dark.png");   

$( window ).scroll(function() {

    if( $j('.scroll_header_top_area').hasClass('scrolled'))
    {
        $j(".q_logo img").attr("src","path_to_image/light.png");
    }
    else{
        $j(".q_logo img").attr("src","path_to_image/dark.png");
    }
});
```

Comment: The only problem is that it doesn't load the first image (dark) on page load, it works for both on scroll.

Comment: Actually, if I add this before your code it all works great : $j(".q_logo img").attr("src","path_to_img/dark.png");