# Wait until .loading class is removed for all id's(removeClass("loading")) and enable button

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I check if loading class is no more on the page and enable a button?

right now I check it like below:

```
if (!($('.loading').length > 0)){

console.log("page loading is done")

}
```

This doesn't seem to work. It only checks it once and nothing happens as we still have loading class assigned to one of the id's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fire an event on class change using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401633/how-to-fire-an-event-on-class-change-using-jquery)

Comment: Can you please share your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval method of javascript like

```
setInterval(function(){ 
   if (!($('.loading').length > 0)){
       console.log("page loading is done") 
       clearInterval(interval); 
   }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and suggestions. I am using setInterval.

Comment: Your welcome @Raj if it will help ful for you can you plaese vote it for a true answer

Answer (score 0):

Clean way is to find a place where .loading class removed and attach your code there (ideally by firing event there and attaching in your code).

Try to search for `removeClass('.loading')` or just `.loading` and add your code right there or fire event via

```
$(document).trigger('my-event-loaded');
```

And then

```
$(document).on('my-event-loaded', function() {
    console.log("page loading is done");
});
```

There is also a really dirty way - to check it periodically:
(AVOID WHEN POSSIBLE)

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (!($('.loading').length > 0)) {
        console.log("page loading is done");
        clearInterval(interval); 
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: I am using loading class for many table in the same form, I want the button to be disabled after all tables are loaded. setInterval worked for now. Thanks for the quick reply and suggestions. These are really helpful.

Comment: In that case those clear way to do things is to check for .loading presence on event fired after each .loading removal - like you do with setInterval $(document).on('my-event-loaded', function() {
    if (!($('.loading').length > 0)) {
        console.log("page loading is done");
    }
});