# Looking for Javascript / jQuery Event trigger

Tags: javascript

I have got a javascript based menu generator that is from an external source. The menu functionality occurs via a click event bound to a specific ID... pretty standard.

What I want to do is perform another action on the DOM **AFTER** that click event fires.

I would rather not hack the code that came in the menu package.

I tried attaching my own click handler - but there isn't an obvious way of ensuring my click handler fires AFTER the menu system's handler.  One approach I considered was basing an event on the addition/removal of a class that occurs with the menu system's click handler. But - I quickly found that there is no event based on the change of class on an element (that I know of).

Any ideas?  (without hacking the original menu system's js)

Comment: This might be helpful (Look at the updated part of the answer): https://stackoverflow.com/a/19401707/6400614

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I saw that - or one similar. I don't think it will work because it is the Navigation System that actually changes the class. 

Yes - if I was changing the class, I wouldn't need another handler, I'd just do the additional work on the DOM then and there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the javascirpt [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), here is a great article about the subject : [Listening to the DOM changes with MutationObserver](https://medium.com/@abbeal/listening-to-the-dom-changes-with-mutationobserver-b53a068a58d2)

**OR** in an old fashion

If I understand, (1) you can add your own click event listener, (2) you want execute your code after a class name change on the menu element.

In that case, you can use a `setInterval` to check if the class has changed and if so, trigger your action.

Something like that :

```
myOnClickFunction(){

    var menu = document.querySelector('#MyMenuID');

    var timer = setInterval(() => {

        if(menu.classList.contains('TheClassNameYouWantToCheck')){
            //Clear the interval 
            clearInterval(timer);

            //Execute your actions here

        }

    }, 50);


    //You can also add a maximum checking  time
    //after 5 seconds the function stop checking for changes
    setTimeout(()=>clearInterval(timer), 5000);

}
```

Comment: Both sound like good ideas.  I'm curious about the Mutation Observer. I did see that but it seemed like dropping a 1000 lb bomb when a mousetrap would do the trick :) 

Never thought of  setInterval... I could use it here or elsewhere.