# How to run setTimeout() until a specific event?

Tags: jquery

On click I want to check if foo has class of bar if not then check again after 5 seconds if so then perform action and stop checking.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $( "#foo" ).click(function() {
    function bar(){
      if $(this).hasClass('bar') {
        return true;
      } else {
    setTimeout(bar, 5000);
      }
    }  
  });
});
```

Ive tried to create a function called bar which checks if foo has class of bar if not then wait 5 seconds and try again. I am executing this once foo has been clicked but something isn't working.

How can I check a div has class if so perform an action if not check again every 5 seconds until it has a class?

Comment: you never run bar.... and you have a bunch of syntax errors in your code

Answer (score 0):

To continuously run some logic use an interval instead of a timer. To clear the interval, save a reference to it and then call `clearInterval()` when the relevant condition is met. Something like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $foo = $('#foo'),
    interval;

  function bar() {
    if ($foo.hasClass('bar')) {
      console.log('class added!');
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }

  $foo.click(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    if (!$foo.hasClass('bar'))
      interval = setInterval(bar, 5000);
  });
});
```

*However* it should be noted that a much better way to achieve what you require is to use a MutationObserver which will trigger your logic when the class is added, without the need to constantly poll the DOM.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19401707/519413) is an answer detailiing how that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax issues, you do not call bar so it never runs, and issues with this since setTimeout changes the scope to window.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var timer;
  $("#foo").on("click", function() {
    if (timer) return
    function bar() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('bar')) {
        timer = null;
        console.log("It was added")
      } else {
        timer = setTimeout(bar.bind(this), 1000);
      }
    }
    bar.apply(this)
  });
})

window.setTimeout(function () {
  $("#foo").addClass("bar")
}, 1000 * (Math.random() * 20))
```

```css
.bar {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="foo">click</button>
```

To avoid the binding, you can move the this outside the method so you are not always look up the element.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var timer;
  $("#foo").on("click", function() {
    if (timer) return
    var btn = $(this)
    function bar() {
      if (btn.hasClass('bar')) {
        timer = null;
        console.log("It was added")
      } else {
        timer = setTimeout(bar, 1000);
      }
    }
    bar()
  });
})

window.setTimeout(function () {
  $("#foo").addClass("bar")
}, 1000 * (Math.random() * 20))
```

```css
.bar {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="foo">click</button>
```