# Alerting a message when the class changes in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am just trying to alert a message when a class is added to a div. The class is added after the document ready so I figured I would have to use the LIVE function ?

Am I right so far ?

This is what I am trying to implement but I have no luck.

I have done a click function test just to verify that the classes are actually right and they are.

> if ( $(".profile-tabs .favourite").live("hasClass","active") ) {
>         alert('test');   };

Can someone give me a hand ? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Fire event if CSS class changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fire the event using jquery trigger and same event you can bind with div.

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#mydiv").addClass("Divcss").trigger('cssChange')
});

$("#mydiv").bind('cssChange', function(){ alert('test'); });
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tr97U/)