# How to run a JS function when CSS class is changed

Tags: javascript, css, events

I have an HTML like:

```
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class=""><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Edit</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Add</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Details</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab2">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically there are tabs. When user clicks on some `<li>` element, CSS class `active` is being added to an appropriate `div` element.

So I want to run a JS function when the first tab is active. How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: And what is changing the class, classes don't change themselves ?

Comment: How are you adding the class to the div ?

Comment: the function that will be called, what will it do? maybe there is a better way to achieve that action, possibly with css if we're talking about style changes like hiding and showing etc..

Comment: What's wrong with just assigning a click event listener to your first tab?

Comment: Actually don't know, cause I'm working on the existed project. When clicking on tab, classes are being changed.

Comment: @knitevision and how can it be done? sorry but i'm totally new in JS

Comment: I don't think there is an 'onclasschange' event, but there must be a JavaScript that adds the class. So all you need to do is find the code that adds the class, and at that place also execute your code. You could even trigger your own event there to separate the code, but maybe that just complicates things for you. If interested, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. It will work.

```
$("li").click(function(){

  if($(this).hasClass('active'))
  {
    alert("hii");
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the onClick() event to each of your anchors.  That way, every time someone clicks on any one of  the "nav-tabs", it triggers the javascript event:

e.g:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" onClick="runThisFunction()">Add</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

On user events only you can check if the class is added to the particular div or not 
there is other way if you are using angular.js, if you want to write using Java Script/Jquery you cannot do that.