# jQuery do code if class is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to check does li inside other li having class is-visible, and in that case do nothing, but if it doesn't add style width: 0px.

```
if (jQuery("li:has(li.is-visible)")){
    //nothing at this moment
}
else {
    jQuery('ul.cd-gallery li').css({'width' : '0px'});
}
```

html part of code

```
<ul class="cd-item-wrapper">
        <li data-type="sve" class="is-visible">
        <img class="img-reponsive" src="someimg.jpg" alt="Jabuka" height="150" />
        </li>
        <li data-type="proizvodi" class="is-hidden">
            <img class="img-reponsive" src="someimg.jpg" alt="Jabuka" height="150" />
        </li>
        <li data-type="vocnaci" class="is-hidden">
            <img class="img-reponsive" src="someimg.jpg" alt="Jabuka" height="150" />
        </li>                       
    </ul>
</li>
```

but I'm using jQuery to change class from is-hidden to is-visible and vice versa. So my code does not see any changes, and I have group all to display all images. If it helps here is link to that page [my site](http://eramond.com/galerija/)

mine Jquery code is good, at least i think, but issue is (if u do inspect element on site) u see bunch of

and wehn u change category i need to hide elements (width:0) that dont't have li > ul > li class="is-visible"

Comment: Use `if($('li').hasClass('is-visible')) {} else {}`.

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed what you are looking for?

Comment: Problem is that there are so many li elements, and in any case at least one have is-visible so i always get same response, have try with 'if (jQuery("li:has(li.is-visible)").length){'and did try all other ideas still no success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect if an element has a class either by using `hasClass()` (*which is recommended as [it's fastest](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-vs-hasclass/2)*):

```
if ( $("li > ul > li").hasClass('is-visible')) {
    //nothing at this moment
} else {
    $('ul.cd-gallery li').css({
        'width', '0px'
    });
}
```

or `is()`:

```
if ( $("li > ul > li").is('.is-visible')) {
    //nothing at this moment
} else {
    $('ul.cd-gallery li').css({
        'width', '0px'
    });
}
```

Comment: Need the dot for class selector when using `is()`. Also I think the OP missed some of his HTML because he said "li inside other li", so the selectors would need to be `$("li > ul > li.is-visible")`.

Comment: Thank you @Tim for the corrections :) I have just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.hasClass()` in jquery. The `.hasClass()` method will return true if the class is assigned to an element, even if other classes also are

```
if(jQuery("li").hasClass('is-visible')){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The check

```
if (jQuery("li:has(li.is-visible)")){
```

is always going to be true since it returns a jQuery object. Objects are truthy. It is not like getElementById which returns a falsey value. You would need to check the length.

```
if (jQuery("li:has(li.is-visible)").length){
```

Zero would be false and any number would be true.

Other option would be to use `is()` or `hasClass()` which returns a Boolean.

Comment: Was'nt part of OP's question is to do the section of script on change of classes? So how to find/ detect if a certain element class has changed from one to another?

Comment: Wonder why this is down voted. Valid answer to why it never would go into the else.