# how do i set html contents in the <body> using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have:

```
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" contenteditable="true" 
    class="bootsy required form-control bootsy_text_area wysihtml5-editor" 
    spellcheck="true" 
    style="color: rgb(85, 85, 85); cursor: auto; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; letter-spacing: normal; text-align: start; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: auto; word-break: normal; word-wrap: break-word; word-spacing: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
</body>
```

I used the following code, but it's not working:

```
if ($("body").hasClass("wysihtml5-editor")) {
     $("body").html('this is a test content.');
});
```

I am using bootsy in my rails app, which generates this body tag in my source code in the browser.So, i want to first find out this body tag with class and then set some value to it using jquery. Please help me out.

Comment: You can only set the value of an element used for user input. What do you actually want to change?

Comment: Whats the extra close tag at very end for?

Comment: What is `this` in your code? If that code is in an event handler, `this` will be the target of the event, not the body. If you want to set the contents of the body, why don't you write `$("body").html()`?

Comment: Sir,still not getting the html in the <body>.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div value="" marginwidth="0" id="bodyId"  marginheight="0" contenteditable="true" 
    class="bootsy required form-control bootsy_text_area wysihtml5-editor" 
    spellcheck="true" 
    style="color: rgb(85, 85, 85); cursor: auto; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; letter-spacing: normal; text-align: start; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: auto; word-break: normal; word-wrap: break-word; word-spacing: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">zxcv</div>
```

Here is the Javascript! Also don't forget to include your Jquery Library! https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js

Here is the JS!

```
    $("body").replaceWith("thing");
    $( "body" ).attr( "value", "Beijing Brush Seller" );
```

Comment: The text-editor i am using is basically a gem, which is auto generated. I have no id for this, that's why i have only class to deal with.

Comment: That's fine! I've updated the answer for you. Id's are generallly the best way to go because you want to be as specific as possible usually, but just accessing body is fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's an easier way to do it:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.wysihtml5-editor').append('<span>Your HTML content.</span>');
});
```

You can insert HTML with `append` or `prepend`.

More information:

- http://api.jquery.com/append/
- http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Comment: @Udaykumardas Maybe you should fire a event and them change the content? See answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed