# Show alert on class change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been busy for some time now and can't seem to get this one. It should be really simple (I guess).

I have a form on my site with `ID #form-custom`. When you click on the submit button and some fields are not correct, it will display an error message and a class will be added to the form, `class .error`.

What I am trying to do is add an eventlistener or something else that displays an alert when the class of `#form-custom` changes to `id="form-custom" class="error"`.

So far I have tried these codes:

```
document.getElementById("form-custom").addEventListener("click", classchange);
    function classchange() {
        if document.hasClass.("error");
        alert("boe");
    }
```

and

```
if ($("#form-custom").hasClass('error')) {
            alert('boe.');
        });
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('form#form-custom').click(function(){    
        if ($(this).hasClass('error')) {
            alert('boe.');
        }
    });
}
```

And some variations of these codes. But non do what I would like them to do...

Could some one help me out?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed

Comment: `$(this).addClass('invalid');
 $("#form-custom").trigger('cssClassChanged')

 $(".invalid").bind('cssClassChanged', data, function(){ alert("boe") });`

I don't really get that answer, could you please review my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form submit should be the event that should work for your situation

```
$('#form-custom').on("submit", function()
{
     if($(this).hasClass("error"))
     {
         alert("Validation fail message");
         return false;
     }

     // submit form

});
```

Comment: You should set a timeout to ensure the class was set by previous onSubmit call

Comment: Thanks for the code. But no go for me... It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)
I would use something like this:

```
$("#form-custom").on("submit",function(){
    var me = $(this);
    // wait for the other onSubmit to set class
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(me.hasClass("error")) {
            alert("error")
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But no go for me... It didn't work.

Could I modify this code in such away that it will always give an alert, just to see if this code works? Like change the status of the "submit" to something else?

Comment: remove the if -clause... you need to click on the submit-button or press enter in an input inside the form. Also i expect, that you already added the function to add the class to the form if some fields are invalid.