# event handler for active/not-acive YADCF filters

Tags: jquery, datatables, yadcf

I am using Datatables 1.10 and YADCF 0.8.9.beta.24.

My filter inputs are shown in a dropdown menu inside each table head `th`. 
I want to show/hide an active-filter-icon in the `th` where a filter is applied, but I don't know how to react properly to any change / selecting / remove event with the different YADCF filter types, specially with the YADCF clear button.
(I'm using `select2`, `text`, `range_date` and `auto_complete`).

What I tried:

```
$('#my-table thead').on('change', function(e) {
  if( $(e.target).val() ) {
    $(e.target).closest('th').addClass('filtered_col');
  } else {
    $(e.target).closest('th').removeClass('filtered_col');
  }
});

//Change event triggers when selecting with 'select2' 
//and when removing items with Select2 remove button, 
//works also selecting with 'auto_complete' filters 
//but not whith any YADCF clear button 
//or when selecting with type 'text' or 'range_date'.
```

I tried with specific event hanlers for Select2 filters ('selecting' and 'removed'), but those are not fired when using the YADCF clear button.

I also tried:

```
oTable.on( 'search.dt', function() {
    $(this).find('th').each(function() {
      if ( $(this).find('.select2-search-choice').length || $(this).find('.inuse').length ) {
        $(this).addClass('filtered_col');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('filtered_col');
      }
    });
});

//It works selecting with 'auto_complete' and with 'text' types.
//and with respective YADCF Clear button.
//also selecting with 'select2' type and clearing with Select2 clear button,
//but NOT clearing select2 with YADCF clear button 
//'range_date' is not being targeted here.
```

So, how could I react to active filters to show and hide an active icon when the user filters each column?

**EDIT**: As suggested in @Daniel's Answer (thank you :), I tried to listen to `DOMSubtreeModified`:

```
  $('#main_container').find('.yadcf-filter-wrapper').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).closest('th').find('.select2-search-choice').length || $(e.target).closest('th').find('.inuse').length ) {
      $(e.target).closest('th').addClass('filtered_col');
    } else {
      $(e.target).closest('th').removeClass('filtered_col');
    }

  });
  //Event is only firing with 'select2' filtering and clearing
  //No other filter types are firing this event, although one CSS class is being added in 'text' filters.
```

Soo, I tried now to modify jquery's `addClass` / `removeClass`, to make them trigger some events (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14084869/4681687)):

```
  (function(){
    var originalAddClass = jQuery.fn.addClass;
    var originalRmvClass = jQuery.fn.removeClass;
    jQuery.fn.addClass = function(){
      // Execute the original method.
      var result = originalAddClass.apply( this, arguments );
      // trigger a custom event
      jQuery(this).trigger('cssClassAdded');
      // return the original result
      return result;
    }
    jQuery.fn.removeClass = function(){
      var result = originalRmvClass.apply( this, arguments );
      jQuery(this).trigger('cssClassRmvd');
      return result;
    }
  })();

  // And then..
  $(function() {
    $('.yadcf-filter-wrapper').on('cssClassAdded', function(){ 
      if( $(this).closest('th').find('.select2-search-choice').length || $(this).closest('th').find('.inuse').length ) {
        $(this).closest('th').find('.fa-filter').css('display', 'block');
      }
    });
    $('.yadcf-filter-wrapper').on('cssClassRmvd', function(){ 
      if( !$(this).closest('th').find('.select2-search-choice').length && !$(this).closest('th').find('.inuse').length ) {
        $(this).closest('th').find('.fa-filter').css('display', 'none');
      }
    });
  });
  //This is the best approach, since is working with 'text', 'select2' and 'auto_complete', with both filtering and clearing actions.
  //'range_date' is the only one I still need to cover.
```

As said, with this last example I could solve the problem in all filter types but 'range_date'. The only idea I have now is, as suggested by @Daniel, to modify YADCF to introduce some class in this case (for manteinance reasons I'd like to avoid this).

I expected that 'inuse' class would be added as well in `range_date` filters. It would do the trick, with my last approach. Is YADCF so desiged, to only introduce this class in some filter types and not in all of them? Maybe I am missing something?

I still would appreciate any better solution to solve this, specially for 'range_date', which I couldn't solve at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to listen to dom change event of the filters because when filter in use yadcf adds a class `inuse` to the filter and when filter is being cleared the `inuse` class is being removed, it will work for most of the filters (except select2) for select2 you can patch yadcf to add / remove the `inuse` class to the select filter (not the the visible one but the original one that gets the `select2-offscreen` class when select2 is being created)

For example

```
$('.yadcf-filter').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(e) {
      alert('class changed');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. But actually, only the 'select2' filters are firing this `DOMSubtreeModified` event, 'text', 'date-range' and 'auto_complete' are not (although `inuse` class is being added in the case of 'text' filters).

Comment: Please, see my 'EDIT' in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just found a different (& easier) way to archive this.
Maybe it helps someone else.

Just hook on the "draw" event from the datatable and add/remove a css class depending on oSavedState.columns...

```
    $('#my-table').on('draw.dt', function (e, oSettings) {
            var th = $('tr th',this); // find all TH elements of current table

            $.each(oSettings.oSavedState.columns, function( index, col ) {
                if (th.length > index){
                    if (col.search && col.search.search != ""){ // filter is active
                        $(th[index]).addClass('filtered_col'); // add class to col's TH
                    } else {
                        $(th[index]).removeClass('filtered_col'); // remove class from col's TH
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Rest is css...

Should work using any filter-plugin or even manually added filters.

UPDATE:

If you don't use stateSave on your datatable, (or even then - it's even shorter) it might be better to use aoPreSearchCols instead of oSavedState.columns:

```
    $('#my-table').on( 'draw.dt', function (e,oSettings) {
        var th = $('tr th',this);
        $.each(oSettings.aoPreSearchCols, function( index, search ) {
            if (th.length > index){
                if (search.sSearch != ""){
                    $(th[index]).addClass('col-filtered');
                } else {
                    $(th[index]).removeClass('col-filtered');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```