# Trigger an event after adding a class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider and it's automatically changing the contents.

```
<div class="main-slider">
  <div class="slide slide-active" data-num="1"> <img> </div>
  <div class="slide"  data-num="1"> <img> </div>
  <div class="slide" data-num="2"> <img> </div>
  <div class="slide"  data-num="3"> <img> </div>
</div>
```

Here when slider is working this slide-active class is automatically changed to next slide .

What I need is, I need to trigger an event when slide active class is changed . For example I need to alert the corresponding `data-num` value of active slide.

How I can do this ?

Comment: the place where you are adding `slide-active` class to next element , there you can trigger.

Comment: Which slide plugin are you using?

Comment: Are you using a jQuery plugin for the slideshow? If yes, then it probably has an event like `onSlide` (or something similar) where you can get the `data-num` of the slide.

Comment: yes . I am using flexslider

Comment: After searching i get the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed#answer-14084869 .

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using FlexSlider refer the original documentation.
It has an event called `after` which will fire when a slide gets animated.

```
$(".main-slider").flexslider({
  after: function(){
     alert($(".slide-active:eq(0)").attr("data-num"));
  }
});
```

Hope this might helps...

Read more about here
https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties

Comment: for some reason after is not working . Start function is working . That's why i posted here . How we can achieve this without using  .flexslider

Comment: You have to use your flex slider init class name. In your case it is main-slider

Answer (score -1):

if id didn't get it wrong your code already moves `slide-active` class to the next slide, right?
so for making the slider you need a for loop and you set var i and add one to it each time. ( start from 0 index num untill your `slide` class number )
you should add the alert event in the for loop so when ever slide changed it triggers alert.

this might be a little confusing so plz add your JS code so i can help u better

good luck